# receive method in Akka actor

Tags: pattern-matching, akka, actor

I have following implementation for receive method in Akka actor implementation.

```
override def receive: Receive = {
  case SetRequest(key, value) =>{
    log.info("Received SetRequest - key:{} ,value:{}", key,value)
    map.put(key,value)
    sender() ! Status.Success
  }
  case GetRequest(key) => {
    log.info("Received GetRequest for - key:{}", key)
    val response: Option[Object] = map.get(key)
    response match {
      case Some(x) => sender() ! x
      case None => sender() ! Status.Failure(new KeyNotFoundException(key))
    }
  }
  case o => Status.Failure(new ClassNotFoundException())
}
```

I have few queries here.

In Actor.scala, receive is defined as:

```
def receive: Actor.Receive
```

Actor.Receive is:

```
type Receive = scala.PartialFunction[scala.Any, scala.Unit]
```

So how does my code in receive conforms to Actor.Receive?

Second, what is this style of pattern matching?receive seems to receive no argument, so what am I actually trying to match?For eg., in code I match response,which makes sense as response is calculated before it is pattern matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how does my code in receive conforms to Actor.Receive? ... What is
>   this style of pattern matching?

In Scala, `case` is a common kind of partial functions.  For example:

```scala
val oneOrTwo: PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
  case 1 => "one"
  case 2 => "two"
}
// oneOrTwo: PartialFunction[Int,String] = <function1>

val reciprocal: PartialFunction[Double, Double] = { case i if i != 0 => 1 / i }
// reciprocal: PartialFunction[Double,Double] = <function1>
```

Hence `case` partial functions can be used to implement `receive` which has the `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]` signature.

The `Any` argument type allows you to use `case` to check against an `input` of any kind you wish (e.g. `SetRequest(key, value)`, `GetRequest(key)` in your sample code).

On the return type, `Unit` allows you to put in any message processing code (e.g. `sender() ! Status.Success`, `response match {...}` in your sample code) and does not demand a return value.

> `receive` seems to receive no argument, so what am I actually trying
>   to match?

Your class extends `Actor`, so when overriding `receive`, you need to implement the method declared in trait `Actor` (see below, from [Akka source code](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/Actor.scala)) which you already did with your `case` partial function.

```scala
object Actor {
  type Receive = PartialFunction[Any, Unit]
  // ...
}

trait Actor {
  def receive: Actor.Receive
  // ...
}
```

By extending `Actor` and implementing method `receive`, Akka equips your class with all the message-driven actor features including a [mailbox](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/actors.html#mailbox) and designates a dispatcher to feed any messages sent to it (e.g. `myActor ! GetRequest(key)` from another actor) as `input` to the `receive` method.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Scala does a lot behind the scenes, and it surely makes difficult to master it.

Comment: Glad that it helps.  Scala blends the disparate OOP and FP in a feature-rich package hence isn't the easiest language to pick up.  That, coupled with Akka's Actor model which is drastically different from conventional concurrency models, does demand some effort to master even the basics.

Answer (score 0):

A partial function comes from mathematics and is opposed to a total function. A total function is defined for all inputs like this one:

```scala
val f = (i: Int) => i + 10
```

Function f produces a valid result for any input of type Int.
However this partial function:

```scala
val g = (i: Int) => 10/i
```

does not (zero would result in an error).

In Scala you can create these special functions like so:

```scala
val h: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
  case i: Int if i != 0 => 10/i
}
```

It has a methdod `isDefinedAt` which can be used to check if it produce a valid result for a given input:

```scala
h.isDefinedAt(0) // false
h.isDefinedAt(5) // true
```

You can call partial functions like normal functions:

```scala
h(5)
```

But they also allow you to chain and combine them like regular functions with `orElse`. Example:

```scala
val x: PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
  case i: Int if i = 10 => "ten"
}

val y: PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
  case i: Int if i = 5 => five"
}

val z = y orElse x

z(10) // "ten"
z(5)  // "five"
z(0)  // MatchError
```

Alone they are able to handle one case each, combined they can handle two.

**To your second question:** `receive` is an unimplemented method in the Actor trait. It will be called somewhere in the Akka implementation with your message. It returns a partial function so it can be combined with the default Akka messages like `PoisonPill` and so on.